# amchart Stacked column chart combined line chart

Tags: amcharts

I'm using amchart.js for my charts. I have a stacked column chart along with multiple line charts combined in a single chart.Problem is along with the bar chart my line chart is also getting stacked.[Screenshot of the final chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYDm1.png)

Comment: Show some code and things you tested/searched to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some of the graphs not stack, set their [`stackable`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#stackable) property to `false`. I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
  // column graph #1
  // ...
}, {
  // column graph #2
  // ...
}, {
  // line graph #1
  // ...
  "stackable": false
}, {
  // line graph #2
  // ...
  "stackable": false
}]
```